# Condensing PHP Arrays?

Tags: php, html, arrays, echo

Hello I have the following code to generate my navigation/page menu along with applying a style element to the active page. I'd like to know how I can go about condensing the code rather than having two merging arrays?

Here's my current code, the difference between the two is the html link outputs. The 'Home' link needs to be `<a href="./'. $k .'">'. $v .'</a>`

Whereas the other pages need to have `<a href="./?p='. $k .'">'. $v .'</a>`

```
<?php

    $current = array(
    "" => "Home"
    );
    foreach( $current as $k => $v ) {
        $active = $_GET['p'] == $k
        ? ' class="current_page_item"'
        : '';
    echo '<li'. $active .'><a href="./'. $k .'">'. $v .'</a></li>';
    }

    $current = array(
        "contact" => "Contact Us",
        "about" => "About Us",
        "privacy" => "Privacy Policy"
    );
    foreach( $current as $k => $v ) {
        $active = $_GET['p'] == $k
            ? ' class="current_page_item"'
            : '';
        echo '<li'. $active .'><a href="./?p='. $k .'">'. $v .'</a></li>';
    }

?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: `if ($v != "Home") $k = '?p=' . $k` is the only change you'd need to have one loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$current = array(
    "" => "Home"
    "contact" => "Contact Us",
    "about" => "About Us",
    "privacy" => "Privacy Policy"
);
foreach( $current as $k => $v ) {
    $active = $_GET['p'] == $k
        ? ' class="current_page_item"'
        : '';
    echo '<li'. $active .'><a href="./'.(empty($k)?"":"?p=") . $k .'">'. $v .'</a></li>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same

$href =empty($k) ? "./" : "./?p={$k}" ;